How do I find a solution on this kind of partition problem on MacOS?
I was trying to install a Linux distro on my brother's old Macbook. Not knowing anything about MacOS, I've let my brother do all the work with partitions/containers. During the installation of Linux we've had a problem and we ended up deleting the partition of 400GB on which Linux was installed. Now we're left with this situation:

Deleting the partition, all the free space disappeared (I can see it only in diskutil). Our goal would be to regain the lost space and trying to reinstall Linux, while mantaining the current MacOS installation.

I've seen online that FFFFF something under dev/disk0 could be a problem but I don't understand. Someone
Thanks to everyone leaving an answer! Sorry, but it has been all day trying to figure it out and I didn't find a solution...
EDIT: not one single partition with linux installed, but a dual boot with Linux and MacOS

Doesn’t your chosen Linux distro have installation steps for preparing the disk? It seems you just need to erase things, no? That container disk is for macOS which you make no mention of needing to have around, so it is dispensable.  What did you leave out of the details?

Alberto: If you still are having problems, post a comment. You probably can fix your problem by using your Linux installer, if you can boot to a Live version.
